How to derive the magnetic field at a distance $x$ (in the same plane) from the centre of a circular loop with current $I$ and radius $R$?
how to get the expression for magnetic field at any point in a circular loop (plane) with current $I$ and radius $R$, I can't seems to find it anywhere and all I'm getting is the derivation for distance on the axis but i want it on the plane to really understand the distribution of magnetic field. I know that we can use integration and biot-savart law
$dB = \dfrac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \dfrac{I \, dl \, \sin \, \theta}{r^2} \label{eq2}$
but don't really know how.
I would appreciate the answer with steps.


Digram wise, you don't need the leads, just make it a superconducting ring. js.

@JEB ya, but I was just being creative.

I'm fairly sure what you're asking for involves an elliptic integral.

Your formula is not really a derivative, it's more of differential element (of an integral).
Moreover, you have cast the vector nature of the problem to the wind:
$$ d\vec B(\vec r) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}
\frac{Id\vec l \times (\vec r-\vec r_l)}{|\vec r- \vec r_l|^3}
$$
where $\vec r - \vec r_l$ is the displacement vector connecting the point at $x$ to the current element $d\vec l$. (Note: the physics cannot depend on your choice of origin, so it should only depend on displacement vectors, and not a general $\vec r$, which is not really a vector (since it depends on origin choice), it's an affine point).
Now with out loss of generality we can define $x \rightarrow (x, 0, 0)$ (the later zero is defined by the in-plane requirement, the former is from azimuthal symmetry).
Then:
$$ \vec B(x, 0, 0) = 0\hat x + B_y\hat y + B_z\hat z $$
but, I think I want to put that in cylindrical coordinates $(\rho, \theta, z)$, and write the integral form for the $z$ component (since we know by symmetric that $B_{\theta}=B_{\rho}=0$:
$$ B_z = \frac{I\mu_0}{4\pi}
\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}
\frac{(Rd\theta)(\vec r -\vec r_l)_z}
{|\vec r -\vec r_l|^3}$$
At this point, you need to so some basic trig to get the magnitude and $z$-component of the displacement vector as a function of $\theta$, and then do the integral, or plug it into https://www.wolframalpha.com/calculators/integral-calculator/.
A more sophisticated option is just write the field (maybe use the vector potential, \vec A) as a multipole expansion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion), since as $R\rightarrow 0$ with $IR^2=constant$, it becomes a pure dipole field, then, one just needs to compute the higher order multipoles of a current loop, and plug them in.
That will get into vector spherical harmonics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_spherical_harmonics), but $\vec A \propto hat\theta$ (by symmetry), so it's not that bad.
Appendix: The Displacement Vector.
The nuances in this problem is not generally discussed in introductory classes and the simplistic definition of a vector as direction and magnitude doesn't help.
Basically, we can describe the position of a point as follows (I'll use cartesian coordinates here):
$$ P_0 = (x_0, y_0, z_0) $$
where the coordinates are defined with respect to an origin:
$$ O = (0, 0, 0) $$
Neither of these are vectors, they are points in an affine space. A point in an affine space like this can be described by an origin, $O$, and a displacement vector defined as:
$$ \vec r_0 \equiv P_0 - O = x_0\hat e_x + y_0\hat e_y+ z_0\hat e_z $$
(I put subscripts on $(x, y, z)$ to distinguish coordinate values from the coordinates.).
With the origin an bases ($\hat e_i$) assumed, we can write the vector as:
$$ \vec r_0 = (x_0, y_0, z_0) $$
which is the same way we wrote $P_0$. That their representations look the same causes confusion: one is a point (a geometric concept), and the other is a vector (a different geometric concept).
That is: the LHS of the above equation is a geometric object: a vector, and the RHS is a representation of it.
The representation looks the same as the RHS of the $P_0$ equation, but the LHS is not a vector, it's an affine point.
(Basically, vectors don't have an origin. A force is a force, and doesn't care about $F=0$).
So here we have the origin at the center of the circle, and at which we're calculating the field:
$$ P_0 = (x, 0, 0) \rightarrow x\hat x =\vec r$$
and a point on the loop defined by theta:
$$ P_{\theta} = (R\cos\theta, R\sin\theta, 0)
\rightarrow x_{\theta}\hat x + y_{\theta}\hat y 
= \vec r'
$$
The displacement vector is:
$$ \vec d \equiv \vec r' -\vec r = (R\cos\theta -x)\hat x
+ \sin\theta\hat y $$
